# The path is not a legal form

Tags: c#, forms, path

It gives this error when debug..Button1 is about zip file,then copy it from source to destination..In delete function it deletes files which creation time older than the time that given..
Note: I'm quite new so please give lots of detail in your answer if possible.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Backup._MAIN takeBackUp = new Backup._MAIN();
    try
    {
        takeBackUp.copyFile(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
         MessageBox.Show("done");  //do stuff
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool dater;
    string err = "";
    Backup._MAIN formDelete = new Backup._MAIN();
    DateTime dtp = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    dater = formDelete.deleteFiles(textBox3.Text, dtp,out err);
    if (err.Length > 0)
        MessageBox.Show(err);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

Dll:

```
public void copyFile(string sSource,string sDestination)
{
    string sourcePath = sSource;
    string targetPath = sDestination;
    Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath,"",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    string myBackUp="";
    string fileName;

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(targetPath))
    {
        zip.AddDirectory(sourcePath, "");
        zip.Save(myBackUp);
    }

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
    {
        string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.rar*");

        foreach (string files in fileList)
        {
            // from the path.
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files);
            targetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
            System.IO.File.Copy(files, targetPath, true);
        }
    }
}

public bool deleteFiles(string sSource, DateTime dOlder, out string sError)
{
    string path = sSource;
    sError = "";
    try
    {
        string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach ( string fname in fileList )
        {

            if ( File.GetCreationTime(path + fname) <= dOlder )
            {
                File.Delete(path + fname);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        sError = ex.ToString();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: _It puts the lotion in the basket or it gets the hose again_.  Can you reword your first paragraph, not sure what you mean

Comment: Can you tell us what the actual question is? You just posted code and explained what it does..

Comment: @MickyDuncan now I feel like some fava beans

Comment: I updated it...Question is in the title..The path is not a legal form...Both are them give the same error

Comment: i think your source path is not in a legal form - you should reformat it so that it is correct. If you want a more useful comment, provide the source paths you are using. Also, set breakpoints and step through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles()` returns full pathnames.

However, consider your code:

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path);

foreach ( string fname in fileList)
{
    if ( File.GetCreationTime(path + fname) <= dOlder)
```

You are prefixing the path when you do `path + fname`, which is going to result in an invalid path because `fname` already contains the path.

If the path includes a drive letter, such as `C:\`, then you'd end up with a path like `C:\MyDir\C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt` which will give you the error that you're seeing.

You just need to do `File.GetCreationTime(fname)` (and the same in `File.Delete()`.

Comment: Yeah it worked! Thanks a lot.Could you find the problem in copyFile function?